# WebFlux backoff and multi-threading in a kafka consumer flow

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, exponential-backoff

I have a `Kafka` consumer written in `Java` and `SpringBoot`.
I am using `WebFlux` in order to make a call to trigger some actions on a third party server (and waiting the result of course).
This server has rate limit that is limiting me from making a lot of requests in a short time.
In order to prevent failures I intend to keep on trying calling the server using `WebFlux backoff`:

```
webClientBuilder.build()
.get()
...
.retryWhen(getRetryPolicyOnTooManyRequests())
...

private RetryBackoffSpec getRetryPolicyOnTooManyRequests() {
    return Retry.backoff(20, Duration.ofSeconds(retryBackoffMinimumSeconds))
        .filter(this::is429Error);
}

private boolean is429Error(Throwable throwable) {
    return throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException
        && ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS;
}
```

My questions are about the behavior I should expect from my kafka:

1. What will happen when I'll be `backoff`ing one of my calls? Will I be blocking the thread? Will a new thread be opened to process another message?
2. If I got the default consumer configurations (`max.poll.records`=500, `max.poll.interval.ms`=30000) and my backoff time will get to 5 minutes will the kafka group be rebalanced?
3. If so, is there a smarter way to tackle this issue so I won't get rebalanced
   each time, other than just putting a super high number in `max.poll.interval.ms`